# Real Jwt token Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, token

Im using jwt token for authentication , i want to find from database but i dont know how to access database for checking user instead of hard code usernames

please look the following code =>

start up :

```
          var key = "123456789fsdphvsaihbviasvsifhdsfdsilafhiopadhfiafosia";
        services.AddSingleton<IJwtAuthentication>(new JwtAuthentication(key)); 

        services.AddAuthentication(z =>
        {
            z.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            z.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(z =>
        {
            z.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            z.SaveToken = true;
            z.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JwtSettings.Secret)),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true
            };
        });
```

my jwt token manager :

```
 public class JwtAuthentication : IJwtAuthentication
{
    private readonly DataContext _db;
    private readonly string _key;
    private IDictionary<string, string> db;
    public JwtAuthentication(/*DataContext db,*/ string key)
    {
        // _db = db; 
         db = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        db.Add("user", "password"); 
        _key = key;
    }
    public string Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        /*  if (!_db.Set<Account>().Any(z => z.UserName == username && z.Password == password.Hash()))
              return null;*/
        if (!db.Any(z => z.Key == username && z.Value == password))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)/*,
                new Claim("Authenticated","true")*/
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
}
```

jwt manager interface :

```
 public interface IJwtAuthentication
{
    string Authenticate(string username, string password);
}
```

NOTE : here for test i was using a dictionary but i want to check the user from my database

i would be really thankful if anyone share a tutorial link . 
thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://medium.com/@ozgurgul/asp-net-core-2-0-webapi-jwt-authentication-with-identity-mysql-3698eeba6ff8) is some good example that I personally followed. It may be outdated in some parts but still works.